# AppHub exception stack trace - where to look for?

Tags: windows-phone-7

One app that I published in the marketplace, is getting some crashes reported in the AppHub.
Most of the time those reports help a bit with where to look for the problem, but with one problem I have no clue what could cause the problem.

Anyone any idea?

I'm getting an error of type 'ResourceClientException'
With folling stack trace:

Frame    Image             Function                                                Offset
    0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                     19
    1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            436488
    2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            386545
    3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            540936
    4                           TransitionStub                                          0
    5                           System.ObservableExtensions._Subscribe_b_*3            0

    6                           System.Reactive.AnonymousObserver`1.Error              72

    7                           System.Reactive.AbstractObserver`1.OnError             144

    8                           .AutoDetachObserver.Error                              72

    9                           System.Reactive.AbstractObserver`1.OnError             144

    10                          .*_c__DisplayClass15c._ObserveOn_b__153                80
    11       mscoree3_7.dll                                                            429164
    12       mscoree3_7.dll                                                            185803
    13       mscoree3_7.dll                                                            184423
    14                          System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke     112
    15                          System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke     1564
    16                          System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke                    104
    17                          System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne                       564
    18                          System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl             84
    19                          System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke    80

Comment: `10 ._c__DisplayClass15c._ObserveOn_b__153 80` is about the only bit that doesn't look like system or Rx - is this part of your code by any chance (obfuscated?)? Looks like the crash occurs on the UI Thread, but that's all I can see.

Comment: Hey Paul, yeah the bit that get's me worried is also the fact that I con't see any root calls from within my app! And I do use some nuget libs so no idea where to look for!

Comment: @Depechie how do you see the crashes from AppHub?

Comment: @whihathac details are mentioned here http://www.facenote.info/index.php/items/mobilephone/524.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the original XAP you submitted to the App Hub, then unzip it (use 7zip or whatever). Then load the DLLs related to your project (unless you know which one it probably is) into Reflector (http://www.reflector.net/), and search for *c*_DisplayClass15c.

That will be an anonymous method or delegate, so won't have a proper name. Using the disassembly that Reflector provides you should hopefully be able to work out where abouts in your app it is, and get a better idea of what needs fixing.